# Regular expression and wrap minus

Tags: javascript, regex

Here my code.

```
var string = 'number1 + number2 - number3';
var operators = [
   {o: '+', regex: '\\+'},
   {o: '-', regex: '\\-'}
];

$.each(operators, function(i, operator){
    string = string.replace(
      new RegExp(operator.regex, "g"),
      '<span class="formula-operator">' + operator.o + '</span>'
    );
});
```

My CSS-class is replaced twice. How should I change my regex?

Comment: Игорь, `var operators = [
   {o: '+', regex: '\\+(?![^<]*</span>)'},
   {o: '-', regex: '\\-(?![^<]*</span>)'}
];`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Yes, that is works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookaheads that will make sure we are not inside a span tag.

```
var operators = [ 
   {o: '+', regex: '\\+(?![^<]*</span>)'}, 
   {o: '-', regex: '\\-(?![^<]*</span>)'} 
];
```

The `(?![^<]*</span>)` lookahead will fail a match if the math operator is followed by zero or more characters other than `<` (`[^<]*`) followed by `</span>`.

**This will not work with nested `<span>` tags**, you will need a DOM parser for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the operators array itself, you could use a single regex:

`string = string.replace(/[+-]/g, operator => '<span class="formula-operator">' + operator + '</span>');`

(Otherwise this expression could be build based on the operators themselves)

PS, the second replacement happens because you have a match (`-`) inside `<span class="formula-operator">`

---

*edit*: An example with dynamic building of the expression:

```
var string = 'number1 + number2 - number3';
var operators = ['+','-'];

string = string.replace(
            new RegExp('[' + operators.join('') + ']', "g"), 
      o => '<span class="formula-operator">' + o + '</span>');
```

Comment: Just FYI: no need to escape the `+` and `-` in this character class - `[+-]`

Comment: This is just an example. In real life I have many other replacements.

Comment: The regex string can be build using a collection of any sort (although your current problem would be solved by using another classname such as `formula_operator` ). I've added an example with an operator array. The same could be done with the original array with an extra mapping if it is needed.